# Linux command to replace string in HUGE file with another string

Tags: vim, sed

I have a huge file (8GB), I want replace on the first 30 lines the String LATIN1 with UTF-8 what is the most efficient method? Means exist there a way to use probably sed but to quit after parsed first 30 lines.

VIM was not able to save the file in 3 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the event of a replacement, all programs will make a *copy* of the file with the substitution in place in order to replace the original file ultimately -- they don't want to risk losing the original for obvious reasons.

With perl, you can do this in a one-liner, but that doesn't make it any shorter (well, it probably does compared to vim, since vim preserves history in yet another file, which perl doesn't):

```
perl -pi -e 's,\bLATIN1\b,UTF-8,g if $. <= 30' thefile
```

Comment: It is certainly *not* true that *all* programs will make a copy.  In fact, the solution provided here does not make a backup!

Comment: @WilliamPursell show me proof of the contrary -- ie trace all syscalls. I bet you it does. Would it only be for the fact that after substitution, file sizes are not the same... Edit: what I meant is, it writes a new copy with substitution in places

Comment: It is certainly true that your solution writes to a temporary file and then overwrites the original.  But it does not make a backup, and the original file is indeed lost.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, my initial comment was badly worded, I edited it

Comment: @fge WOW, give your solution a try too. 40 seconds for 8GB awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @Nenad at this level, what gives you performance is the underlying I/O capabilities ;) On a decade-old rig this comment would certainly not take 40 seconds :p

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`, you can quit using `q`:

```
sed -e 's/LATIN1/UTF-8/g' -e 30q
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well, but how I get the result in one file? Actually sed -e 's/LATIN1/UTF-8/g' -e 30q my_old_one > my_new_one will write only the first 30 lines

Comment: The easiest thing would be to followup with : `sed -n '31,$p' my_old_one >> my_new_one`.

Answer (score 0):

untested, but I think `ed` will edit the file in-place without writing to a temp file.

```
ed yourBigFile << END
1,30s/LATIN1/UTF-8/g
w
q
END
```